# Flask: TypeError: downloadanddelete() got multiple values for argument 'file'

Tags: python, web-services, flask, webserver

There are plenty of posts regarding this specific TypeError but none seem to help in my case. I have a function which returns a file from the server but everytime I try to call it this error occurs:

File "services.py", line 75, in decorated
return f(user, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: downloadanddelete() got multiple values for argument 'file'

All I could find online were problems regarding class functions and overwriting positional arguments.

Testing recommendations or pointing to an online resource about the problem would be very much appreciated.

services.py (main)

```
from downlaod import downlaoad
from functools import wraps
from flask import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# create app
app = Flask(__name__)

# config for app --> link database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://////opt/services/databases/users.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

User = database(db=db)

def auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        #request authorization and save data in auth
        auth = request.authorization

        # if auth or username or password are empty
        if not auth or not auth.username or not auth.password:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})

        # find the user
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=auth.username).first()

        # if user is empty
        if not user:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})
        
        # if password is not correct
        if user.password != auth.password:
            return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})
        
        # if password is correct
        if user.password == auth.password:
            # gib user zurück
            return f(user, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated


@app.route('/download/<file>', methods=['GET'])
@auth
def downloadanddelete(file,current_app):
    r = downlaoad(file=file,current_app=current_app)
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8081, host="127.0.0.1")
```

downloadanddelete.py

```
# import Lib
from flask import make_response, Flask, send_file
import os


def downlaod(file,current_app):
    # path of temp
    path = '/opt/services/temp/' + file

    # generate a file in the ram than delete the file from SSD or HDD

    def generate():
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            yield from f 
        os.remove(path)

    r = current_app.response_class(generate())
    r.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', file)
    #send file
    return r
```

---

**Update #1:**
Tried to replicate the error locally and used the exact same code mentioned above. I got a different error:

TypeError: downloadanddelete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'current_app'

I got it working locally on my Windows machine by not passing `current_app` to `downloadanddelete()` and instead importing it from flask :

Services.py changes

```
@app.route('/download/<file>', methods=['GET'])
def downloadanddelete(file):
    return downlaod(file=file)
```

downloadanddelete.py

```
from flask import make_response, Flask, current_app
import os

def downlaod(file):

    path = 'C:\\Users\\my_username\\temp'

    def generate():
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            yield from f 
        os.remove(path)

    r = current_app.response_class(generate())
    r.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
    return r
```

I applied the same changes to the server and got the exact same error as before:

File "services.py", line 75, in decorated return f(user, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: downloadanddelete() got multiple values for argument 'file'

I am currently trying to replicate the error locally, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was in hindsight very simple but the way the code is written can confuse. The `auth()` function returns a user object. So when you use `@app.route` and `@auth` the function expects the current user. If you don't have a user parameter in the called function (downloadanddelete) it will be passed in the first positional parameter and that's why the error occurs.

Solution

```
@app.route('/download/<file>', methods=['GET'])
@auth
def downloadanddelete(user,file,current_app):
    r = downlaoad(user=user,file=file,current_app=current_app)
    return r
```